# UID "not loaded" when using NFT markers

Tags: unity-game-engine, artoolkit

I've been trying to learn ArToolkit for Unity from examples and documents. I able to select square marker and it works perfectly. But when i select NFT for marker type and fill dataset name, UID keeps not loaded. I used genTexData to create datasets and dragged and dropped them to the StreamingAssets on Unity. Even with the example NFT scene it gives me this problem. I also tried copying latest scripts from github and it didn't work. I'm using Unity 5.3.2f1 and ARUnity5-5.3.2 package on Windows 10 and have not much experience with Unity and ARToolkit.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, do you get any error message in the console? Because I just created a new Unity project (Unity 5.3.4f1) and imported ARToolKit package 5.3.2 and drag-droped the SampleNFT.scene in and it works perfectly.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I install 5.3.4.f1 after your comment and tried again. I get following errors. http://i.imgur.com/rTOBpAE.jpg , http://i.imgur.com/04TNK4D.jpg , http://i.imgur.com/OfTaTNu.jpg .

Comment: The GUID error we know about and are in the process to fix them but they should not cause you any trouble except being annoying. The warnings are also know and not critical.

Comment: What troubles me is your first error. It looks like ARTK has trouble with the symbols in your path name. Is it possible for you to create a project directly from C:\ without your user name in the path to evaluate this theory? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Yes that solved the problem, thanks a lot. Great work by the way, the library :).

Comment: Added an official answer. Would be great if you can mark that as valid answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the images you sent in the comments it looks like ARTK has trouble with the symbols in your path name. Please create the project directly from C:\ without your user name in the path. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Regarding the other errors in the images:
The GUID error we know about and are in the process to fix them but they should not cause you any trouble except being annoying. The warnings are also know and not critical.

--edit:--

ARToolKit has trouble with paths using the Turkish extended charset characters: http://www.ascii-codes.com/cp857.html#extended_character_set like Ç,ç,ğ,ş
Please avoid using these characters in paths used by ARToolKit